# Default document font size of doc/docx documents

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to find the default font size of a doc/ docx document using apache poi. I have used the XWPFRun class method getFontSize(). But it returns the value -1 if the font size is default. I couldn't find any other method that returns the same in the documentation. Is there a way i can get the "actal" default font size of the document?

Comment: Did you try checking the font size on the style applied to the run?

Comment: yeah i did, and it is returning correct results. But if the font size of a run is default, it shows -1 (which "means" it is the default font size) and not the actual font size.

Comment: as of 3.12, which said " Initial XWPFStyles support for working with default document paragraph and run styles" and implemented XWPFDefaultRunStyle class. but document.getStyles().getDefaultRunStyles().getFontSize() still returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

```
document.getStyles().getDefaultRunStyles().getFontSize();
```

solved the problem.